# How can i print my array and my histogram on the same line?

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Histogram
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    Row[] numbers = {
           new Row("1  -  10"), new Row("11 -  20"), new Row("21 -  30")                 
           new Row("31 -  40"), new Row("41 -  50"), new Row("51 -  60")
           new Row("61 -  70"), new Row("71 -  80"), new Row("81 -  90"),
           new Row("91 - 100")
                };
for(Row number : numbers)
  System.out.print(number);   
Counter section = new Counter();
section.StarCounter();

}
```

it prints out something like this:

```
1  - 10|
11 - 20|
21 - 30|
*****************
*********
***
ect.
```

I would like it to print out something like:

```
1  - 10|*****************
11 - 20|*********
21 - 30|***
ect.
```

thanks in advance for any pointers, I'm probably just overlooking the obvious.

Counter class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Counter
{
  public void StarCounter() throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File file = new File("alotofnumbers.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
    int[] integers = new int[1000];
    int start = 0;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    int count3 = 0;
    int count4 = 0;
    int count5 = 0;
    int count6 = 0;
    int count7 = 0;
    int count8 = 0;
    int count9 = 0;
    int count10 = 0;

    while (scan.hasNextInt())
    {
  integers[start++] = scan.nextInt();
}

for (int input : integers)
{
  if(input <= 10)
  {
    count1++;  
  }
  else if(input > 10 && input <= 20)
  {
    count2++;
  }
  else if(input > 20 && input <= 30)
  {
    count3++;
  }
  else if (input > 30 && input <= 40)
  {
    count4++;
  }
  else if (input > 40 && input <= 50)
  {
    count5++;
  }
  else if (input > 50 && input <= 60)
  {
    count6++;
  }
  else if (input > 60 && input <= 70)
  {
    count7++;
  }
  else if (input > 70 && input <= 80)
  {
    count8++;
  }
  else if (input > 80 && input <= 90)
  {
    count9++;
  }
  else if (input > 90 && input <= 100)
  {
    count10++;
  }
} 
  double counted1 = count1 / 2.7;
  double counted2 = count2 / 2.7;
  double counted3 = count3 / 2.7;
  double counted4 = count4 / 2.7;
  double counted5 = count5 / 2.7;
  double counted6 = count6 / 2.7;
  double counted7 = count7 / 2.7;
  double counted8 = count8 / 2.7;
  double counted9 = count9 / 2.7;
  double counted10 = count10 / 2.7;

  for(int star = 0; star <= counted1  ; star++)
  {
   System.out.print("*");

  }
  System.out.println();


  for(int star = 0; star <= counted2 ; star++)
  {
    System.out.print("*");
  }

   System.out.println();
   for(int star = 0; star <= counted3 ; star++)
   {
    System.out.print("*");
   }

     System.out.println();

   for(int star = 0; star <= counted4 ; star++)
   {
     System.out.print("*");
   }

    System.out.println(); 
    for(int star = 0; star <= counted5 ; star++)
    {
     System.out.print("*");
    }

      System.out.println();

    for(int star = 0; star <= counted6 ; star++)
    {
      System.out.print("*");
    }

     System.out.println();
     for(int star = 0; star <= counted7 ; star++)
     {
      System.out.print("*");
     }

       System.out.println();

     for(int star = 0; star <= counted8 ; star++)
     {
       System.out.print("*");
     }

      System.out.println();
      for(int star = 0; star <= counted9 ; star++)
      {
       System.out.print("*");
      }

        System.out.println();

      for(int star = 0; star <= counted10 ; star++)
      {
        System.out.print("*");
      }

       System.out.println();     


 }
 }
```

Apparently my post has to much code and I don't really have much more info to give so it wants me to type something random up.
      public class Row
      {
      private String rows;

```
  public Row(String colums)
  {
  rows = colums ;
  }

  public String toString()
  {
  Counter section = new Counter();
  return rows + "|" + "\n";
  }

  public void setRow(String colums)
  {
  rows = colums;
  } 

  public String getRow()
  {
  return rows;
  }

  }
```

Comment: Your `Row.toString` adds a newline. Remove that and you're probably good.

Comment: Did you tried debuger?

Comment: But then my array will print only on the top line I need it to print 1 value per line a time like it does @Robert and then have my stars print right beside that.

Comment: @talex I'm new to java and don't really understand the debugger

Comment: I think in general we should come up with a better way to parse that file of yours and sort them into different buckets. Have you learned about `mod` (`%`) yet?

Comment: I suggest you to learn it. Because it is great tool to troubleshoot problems.

Comment: No I haven't all i really need right now is a way to format it so it outputs correctly, I have class in 4hrs where this is due.

Comment: I'm guessing I will learn about it later in my course, At this point I'm honestly more curious to what my problem is then caring about the %5 I'm going to get docked for not completing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your problem. The problem was that you were printing all of your `Row` data first and then all of your `Integer` data. You need to print them both at once.  Not one after the other.  Also just fyi, there is about a million different ways to make your initial code better. I would try and sit down and think of a better way to do this so you can learn (after you turn in your assignment so you are not rushed, we can all help. This is a good start though.)

First I erased the printing of the `Row` data, and added a constructor to your `Counter` class to take in your `Row` data.

```
Row[] numbers = {
        new Row("1  -  10"), new Row("11 -  20"), new Row("21 -  30"),                 
        new Row("31 -  40"), new Row("41 -  50"), new Row("51 -  60"),
        new Row("61 -  70"), new Row("71 -  80"), new Row("81 -  90"),
        new Row("91 - 100")
};  
Counter section = new Counter(numbers);
section.StarCounter();
```

New Constructor:

```
public class Counter
{
    Row[] numbers;
    public Counter(Row[] numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }
    //Rest of your methods
}
```

Then printed the `Row` data when you print your `Integer` data.

```
System.out.print(numbers[0]);  //new line
for(int star = 0; star <= counted1  ; star++)
{
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print(numbers[1]);  //new line
for(int star = 0; star <= counted2 ; star++)
{
    System.out.print("*");
}
//Do the same for the rest
```

Hope this helps!

Oh also got rid of the newline in your `Row` class.

```
public String toString()
{
    return rows + "|";
}
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, I'm definitely interested in improving my coding, I just shouldn't hand in anything much past this as that's as far as my knowledge from that class has shown me.

Comment: @JadenHambley yup I completely understand. If this solved your problem, please accept the answer. If not, let me know if you have any additional questions on the solution or with the problem you were encountering.

Comment: honestly was trying to print my Row data with the Integer data, but couldn't do it properly, Thanks again though!

Comment: I'm almost positive this is what I'm looking for just gotta get to my desktop to try it out

Comment: Worked perfect, Thanks! @gonzo